# A method to use a formula if , and if not to tip a value manual inside, without VBA Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, manual, automatic-properties

Hello and thanks for the help in advance.

Is there a way, for example, if cell A1 can say either yes or no, then I say in cell A2, if it says yes, then automatically write a word like "tree" in the cell, and if in cell A1 = no then the user should be able to describe/fill in the field in cell A2 manually. So far I haven't found a solution on how the formula doesn't disappear then. I don't want to use Excel-VBA here if possible. This would give me a solution, but since not everyone in my company has macro permissions, it would not be usable for everyone then..

Comment: Not possible by formula.

Comment: Conditional Formatting could do it.  Untested,  but something like condition 
`A1="yes"` with format `;;;"tree"`

Comment: and how does it look like with the A1="yes" and ;;;"tree", so how can I combine this, because if i do ;;;"tree" it always fills in tree, whatever I write into the box. And I want it like 
A1 = "yes", so show A2 = "tree". If A1 = "no", so show nothing and let me write in whatever I want maybe A2 = "car" manual, and A2 should show "car" then